# How to open ranger from neovim and tmux, like Tim Pope`s dispatch do

Tags: neovim, tmux

Archlinux, termite -> tmux -> neovim

I want to open ranger in new pane, and when it ended and pane was closed - open selected file/files. This flow is similar to Tim Pope`s dispatch behavior

```
" inspired by francoiscabrol plugin
function! OpenRanger(dir)
  let currentPath = expand(a:dir)
  let tmp_file_path = tempname()
  exec 'silent !tmux splitw ranger --choosefiles=' . shellescape(tmp_file_path) . ' ' .currentPath
  call system('notify-send "exec is ended"') " debug string, was fired
  if filereadable(tmp_file_path)
    call system('notify-send "tmpfile was readable"') " debug string, wasnt fired
    for f in readfile(tmp_file_path)
      exec 'edit '. f
    endfor
    call delete(tmp_file_path)
  endif
  redraw!
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>f :call OpenRanger('%:p:h')<CR>
nnoremap <leader>F :call OpenRanger('')<CR>
```

How can I force to execute `if filereadable(tmp_file_path)` after pane was closed (on neovim, [which have issues with that](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/issues/279) )?

**This don't work either**

```
function! OpenRanger(dir)
  let currentPath = expand(a:dir)
  let tmp_file_path = tempname()
  let rangerCallback = { 'name': 'ranger' , 'tmp_file_path': tmp_file_path}
  function! rangerCallback.on_exit(id, code)
    call system('notify-send callback') " was fired before I close ranger
    " bdelete!
    if filereadable(self.tmp_file_path)
      for f in readfile(self.tmp_file_path)
        exec 'edit '. f
      endfor
      call delete(self.tmp_file_path)
    endif
  endfunction
  tabnew
  call termopen('tmux splitw ranger --choosefiles=' . shellescape(tmp_file_path) . ' ' . currentPath, rangerCallback)
  startinsert
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/tracyone/t-vim/blob/master/autoload/te/tmux.vim#L26-L45

run ranger using tmux

```
call te#tmux#run_command('ranger',0x01)
```

Comment: you should explain how your plugin achieves it

Comment: This is just a vim function.You can copy it to your own vimrc, change its name.In this function, It just calls tmux with property argument using system function in vim.

Comment: I know what a function is. I want to know, what exactly the function does. E.g. what are the exact tmux commands it will be executing?